# Do beam pipelines preserve ORDER BY in a source query when sourcing from BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a beam pipeline written in Java that we run on GCP Dataflow. Its very simple, it takes a SQL query as a `PipelineOption`, issues that SQL query against BigQuery and for every row in the returned dataset constructs a message and puts it onto a pubsub topic.

```java
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Validation.Required;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * The {@code BigQueryEventReplayer} pipeline runs a supplied SQL query
 * against BigQuery, and sends the results one-by-one to PubSub
 * The query MUST return a column named 'json', it is this column
 * (and ONLY this column) that will be sent onward. The column must be a String type
 * and should be valid JSON.
 */
public class BigQueryEventReplayer {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BigQueryEventReplayer.class);

  /**
   * Options for the BigQueryEventReplayer. See descriptions for more info
   */
  public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("SQL query to be run."
        + "An SQL string literal which will be run 'as is'")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQuerySql();

    void setBigQuerySql(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The name of the topic which data should be published to. "
        + "The name should be in the format of projects/<project-id>/topics/<topic-name>.")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputTopic();

    void setOutputTopic(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The ID of the BigQuery dataset targeted by the event")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQueryTargetDataset();

    void setBigQueryTargetDataset(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The ID of the BigQuery table targeted by the event")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQueryTargetTable();

    void setBigQueryTargetTable(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The SourceSystem attribute of the event")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getSourceSystem();

    void setSourceSystem(ValueProvider<String> value);

  }

  /**
   * Takes the data from the TableRow and prepares it for the PubSub, including
   * adding attributes to ensure the payload is routed correctly.
   */
  // We would rather use a SimpleFunction here but then we wouldn't be able
  // to inject our value providers. So instead we hackishly make a nested class
  public static class MapQueryToPubsub extends DoFn<TableRow, PubsubMessage> {
    private final ValueProvider<String> targetDataset;
    private final ValueProvider<String> targetTable;
    private final ValueProvider<String> sourceSystem;

    MapQueryToPubsub(
        ValueProvider<String> targetDataset, 
        ValueProvider<String> targetTable, 
        ValueProvider<String> sourceSystem) {
      this.targetDataset = targetDataset;
      this.targetTable = targetTable;
      this.sourceSystem = sourceSystem;
    }

    /**
     * Entry point of DoFn for Dataflow.
     */
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      TableRow row = c.element();
      if (!row.containsKey("json")) {
        logger.warn("table does not contain column named 'json'");
      }
      Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
      attributes.put("sourceSystem", sourceSystem.get());
      attributes.put("targetDataset", targetDataset.get());
      attributes.put("targetTable", targetTable.get());
      String json = (String) row.get("json");
      c.output(new PubsubMessage(json.getBytes(), attributes));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Run the pipeline. This is the entrypoint for running 'locally'
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Parse the user options passed from the command-line
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
    run(options);
  }

  /**
   * Run the pipeline. This is the entrypoint that GCP will use
   */
  public static PipelineResult run(Options options) {

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    pipeline.apply("Read from BigQuery query",
        BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(options.getBigQuerySql()).usingStandardSql().withoutValidation()
            .withTemplateCompatibility())
        .apply("Map data to PubsubMessage",
            ParDo.of(
                new MapQueryToPubsub(
                    options.getBigQueryTargetDataset(),
                    options.getBigQueryTargetTable(),
                    options.getSourceSystem()
                )
            )
        )
        .apply("Write message to PubSub", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(options.getOutputTopic()));

    return pipeline.run();
  }
}
```

The BigQuery data being queried is essentially a log of events. We have recently determined that the order in which we insert those events onto the pubsub topic is important. We can determine the correct order by using an ORDER BY in the query that we issue against BigQuery however we are skeptical as to whether that order will be respected when the data gets inserted onto the pubsub topic.

Our main concern is in this code:

```java
pipeline.apply("Read from BigQuery query",
        BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(options.getBigQuerySql()).usingStandardSql().withoutValidation()
            .withTemplateCompatibility())
```

that simple command manifests as this in Dataflow:

[image: dataflow job screenshot of 'Read from BigQuery query']

There is a lot happening in that step (shuffles etc...) and actually many of the sub-steps are themselves made up of multiple sub-steps. Moreover, one of the sub-steps is called "ReadFiles" which makes me think that perhaps Dataflow is writing the data to some sort of temporary file store. All-in-all this leads me to doubt that an ORDER BY in the supplied SQL query will be preserved when the rows get published to pubsub.

Does beam/Dataflow offer any guarantee that the ORDER BY will be preserved in this scenario or am I going to have to introduce a sort into my pipeline to guarantee that the desired order is adhered to?

Comment: Hi OP, you may contact GCP support for better consultation/insights specific to your use case and assist you to have the correct resolution/approach that best fits your use case. https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: Ok thx Scott. Is this not a question about Beam rather than Dataflow specifically though? I doubt Google Support would provide support regarding Beam.

Comment: GCP support will assist you with Dataflow related concerns and they can give suggestions regarding Apache Beam but this is best effort only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BigQueryIO Read basically consists an import job to GCS as Avro for the query/table and then a Read from those files (and some more stuff). So it won't preserve the order, since the reads are in parallel and there will be multiple threads reading chunks of the created file(s).

Generally speaking, distributed processing systems as Dataflow (or Spark, etc) don't preserve order and are bad at ordering stuff given the parallel nature of their job. Bare in mind that to sort elements you need to hold everything in a single worker.

In fact, even in BigQuery, the ORDER BY is quite a demanding task.

It's hard to find workarounds for this, since the systems are not built for this type of tasks. I can think on adding the ROW NUMBER, using that as timestamp and adding a window, but this is quite use case specific.

Also, PubSubIO won't preserve the order when publishing.

Comment: thank you, that confirmed my suspicion